# (Python 3.2):Exit when an if statement doesn't meet a condition

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. I'm writing a program that initially asks for a user's information (name, age, etc.) and I'm trying to figure how to exit the problem if the user's age is under 7. Here is my code so far.

```
def age_func():
  while True:
    try:
        age = int(input('How old are you? '))
        if age > 7:
            print(f'OK! You are {age} years old')
        elif age < 7:
            print("Too young for this game. Come back in a few years.")
        break
    except:
            print("Please enter a number")
```

At first I tried adding an `exit()` statement after the print following the elif statement, but I realize that instead of exiting, the program will just loop back to the first input requesting the user's age. How can I make it so that the program will terminate, so an underage player can't progress?

Thanks everyone!!

Comment: what is the error in this program

Comment: Code output:  How old are you? 5
                      Too young for this game. Come back in a few years.

Comment: "How can I make it so that the program will terminate, so an underage player can't progress?" You should `return` a value that indicates whether the user is old enough, and use that value in the place where you called the function, to decide how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The code you gave works fine when I do this:

```py
def age_func():
  while True:
    try:
        age = int(input('How old are you? '))
        if age > 7:
            print(f'OK! You are {age} years old')
        elif age < 7:
            print("Too young for this game. Come back in a few years.")
        break
    except:
            print("Please enter a number")

age_func()
```

However, if you put the function call inside a loop,

```py
while True:
  age_func()
```

it will not work. I'm guessing that is what happened. You can solve by using `sys.exit()`:

```py
import sys

def age_func():
  while True:
    try:
        age = int(input('How old are you? '))
        if age > 7:
            print(f'OK! You are {age} years old')
        elif age < 7:
            print("Too young for this game. Come back in a few years.")
        sys.exit() #replaced break with sys.exit()
    except:
            print("Please enter a number")

while True:            
  age_func()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `try... except` is catching the exception raised by `exit()`.

A better solution is to not use a catch-all `except`, and instead to use `except ValueError`, which will only catch specific errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please read *entire* post :)

The solution to killing a program is using 'sys.exit()'. So, you would do this:

```py
import sys

def age_func():
  while True:
    try:
        age = int(input('How old are you? '))
        if age > 7:
            print(f'OK! You are {age} years old')
        elif age < 7:
            print("Too young for this game. Come back in a few years.")
        sys.exit() #replaced break with sys.exit()
    except:
            print("Please enter a number")

age_func()
```

Unfortunately, this still does not work, because of your try statement. Exits are considered as errors, so when you try to run 'sys.exit()', it sends "Please enter a number", even if what you typed *was* a number. This is why it is important to specify the exception type, like this:

```py
import sys

def age_func():
  while True:
    try:
        age = int(input('How old are you? '))
        if age > 7:
            print(f'OK! You are {age} years old')
        elif age < 7:
            print("Too young for this game. Come back in a few years.")
        sys.exit() #replaced break with sys.exit()
    except ValueError: #Now it will only except if what you typed wasn't a number, so it will exit properly.
            print("Please enter a number")

age_func()
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to check elif statement because it is understood, if `if age>7` false then it means age will always less than 7 or 7. 
            `def age_func():
                   while True:
                              age = int(input('How old are you? '))
                              if age > 7:
                                   print(f'OK! You are {age} years old')
                              else:
                                   print("Too young for this game. Come back in a few years.")
                                   break`

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

def age_func():
  while True:
    try:
        age = int(input('How old are you? '))
        if age > 7:
            print('OK! You are {age} years old')
        elif age < 7:
            print("Too young for this game. Come back in a few years.")
            sys.exit() 
    except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number")

age_func()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion